# React arrow function receiving the initial state only

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions, use-state, react-state

I'm doing a timer set by a button. I do have some states running but in my arrow function backLunch, I just receive the initial state of timerR.

Here the code;

```
export default function TimeTracker(props) {
  const [buttonLabel, setButtonLabel] = useState("start timer")
  const [buttonAction, setButtonAction] = useState()
  const [timerR, setTimerR] = useState(0)
  let interval

  const startTimer = () =>{
    const startTime = new Date;
    interval = setInterval(async() => {
      
      await setTimerR(new Date-startTime)
    },1000)

    setButtonLabel("lunch brake")
    setButtonAction(()=>lunchBrake)
  }
  const lunchBrake = () =>{
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    setButtonLabel("back from lunch")
    setButtonAction(()=>backLunch)
  }
  const backLunch = () =>{
    const backTime = new Date;
    const totalTime = backTime-timerR;
    interval = setInterval(async() => {
      
      await setTimerR(new Date-totalTime)
    },1000)

    setButtonLabel("back from lunch")
    setButtonAction(()=>goHome)
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setButtonAction(()=> startTimer );
  }, [])



  return (
    <>
      <div className="tracker__header">
        <h2>Time Tracker</h2>
        <span className="tracker__time">
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon__default" icon={faClock}/> 
          {fortmatMilliTimer(timerR)}
        </span>
      </div>

      <div className="tracker__buttons">
        <Button type="attention" text={buttonLabel} action={buttonAction} />
        <Button type="default" text="input time" action={e => props.setModal("input")} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

I'm recieving timerR=0 in my backLunch function.
How can I make it get the actual state of timerR at the time it is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :-

```
const backLunch = () =>{
  const backTime = new Date;
  interval = setInterval(async() => {
    await setTimerR((latestTimerRVal) => {
      const totalTime = backTime - latestTimerRVal;
      return new Date-totalTime; // this will be set as new value ofr timerR
    })
  },1000)

  setButtonLabel("back from lunch")
  setButtonAction(()=>goHome)
}
```

The setter function can take a function as an arg with the latest state value as a parameter. This will probably fix the issue.

The issue is here `setButtonAction(()=>lunchBrake)`. The closure value of `timerR` here is 0. Hence the problem.

Comment: That really works. is that the best way to fix it? I'm doing this code to learn and it would be nice to know a better ways to make this timer;

Comment: So this is the correct way to fix this issue. I would recommend learning about closures in JS - those concepts will make you clearly understand the above issue of getting old value of timerR. About the whole architecture of the timer, you will find plenty on YouTube, this one is good - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAx76xx40jM